# Flask RESTful API: Issue with db connection pool

Tags: python, azure, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm trying to create REST API endpoints using flask framework. This is my fully working script:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_restful import reqparse
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

conn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://x:x@x:1433/x?driver=SQL Server"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.get_password
def get_password(username):
    if username == 'x':
        return 'x'
    return None

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

class Report(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('start', type = str)
        parser.add_argument('end', type = str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        e = create_engine(conn_string)
        conn = e.connect()

        stat = """
        select x from report 
        """

        query = conn.execute(stat)

        json_dict = []


        for i in query.cursor.fetchall():
                res = {'x': i[0], 'xx': i[1]}
                json_dict.append(res)


        conn.close()
        e.dispose()
        return jsonify(results=json_dict)


api.add_resource(Report, '/report')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The issue is that I get results when I call this API only for a day or so after which I stop getting results unless I restart my script (or sometimes even my VM) after which I get results again. I reckon there is some issue with the database connection pool or something but I'm closing the connection and disposing it as well. I have no idea why the API gives me results only for some time being because of which I have to restart my VM every single day. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe think about Flask-SQLalchemy Extension? Helps make this stuff easier.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the issue was caused by coding `create_engine(conn_string)` to create db pool inside the Class `Report` so that always do the create & destory operations of db pool for per restful request. It's not correct way for using SQLAlchemy ORM, and be cause IO resouce clash related to DB connection, see the `engine.dispose()` function description below at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:

[image]

To resolve the issue, you just need to move `e = create_engine(conn_string)` to the below of the code `conn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://x:x@x:1433/x?driver=SQL Server"`  and remove the code `e.dispose()` both in the Class `Report`,  see below.

```
conn_string = "mssql+pyodbc://x:x@x:1433/x?driver=SQL Server"
e = create_engine(conn_string) # To here
```

In the `def get(delf)` function：

```
args = parser.parse_args()
# Move: e = create_engine(conn_string)
conn = e.connect()
```

and

```
conn.close()
# Remove: e.dispose()
return jsonify(results=json_dict)
```

Comment: Hi! I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas? I did exactly as you mentioned above.

Comment: @90abyss Any errors you can got when the issue happened? You can refer to the troubleshoot doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/#diagnostics-log-your-errors to look up errors.